# How can I convert this MATLAB cell array into a Numpy file/Python array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

This is what my variable, call it `A`, looks like in MATLAB (only 10 cells):

[image: A in MATLABe]

Then, this is what the first cell 1,1 looks like (goes on for 20 cells):

[image: A{1,1}]

Then, this is what the first cell of that image looks like (goes on for 32 cells):

[image: A{1,1}{1}]

And, I want to make a `.npy` file that when loaded and saved as variable `data` & then printed, looks like this:

[image: required result in python]

How can I transfer the `.mat` file to a `.npy` so that when I load it, it looks like above?

Comment: Have you tried `scipy.io.loadmat`?  Or are you trying to creat the equivalent in `numpy` from scratch?

Comment: `x=np.zeros((10,20,30))` should have the desired shape.  You could then set a subset of the elements with `x[:,n:,n:] = 1`.